# Spring and thymeleaf with html as resources

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I am learning java ee related technologies (and I am relatively newbie) and try to write simple web application with Spring and Thymeleaf as frontend, and i have some problems with
modularization.

I found that it is used to pack .html filesinto WEB-INF directory for security purposes, but, as far as i guess, it means I have to put there all of my views, have controllers in this projects. I want to avoid that by having many projects for example:

- web-app
- admin-module
- user-module
- core-module

and each of them has its own, module specific controllers and views (htmls) and web-app
combines them all into single, big project.

In Thymelaf i found something like ClassLoaderTemplateResolver and got (maybe stupid idea) how to divide big project into many ones - put htmls into classpath resource directory.
By this I can ask for any html view from any module project. Does this violates some security reasons?

I would like to ask does anyone has similar problem and found proper solution how to elegantly divide html web-app project into many smaller 'context-specific' projects?

Here is my current project structure. Blue arrow idicates which view is connected to which controller:
http://prntscr.com/4tqt9m

This is my first question asked here so I hope you will treat me with some understanding.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You're doing a whole lot of extra work. Use Spring Boot and drop your Thymeleaf files in `src/main/resources/templates`.

Comment: @chrylis Thank you !! I spent more than 2 hours trying to figure out which TemplateResolver to use and all that. I deleted everything and spring boot automatically figured it out -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to merge multiple Spring and Thymeleaf modules at runtime using classpath lookup. Just make sure you give different qualified name / folder structure (eg: two files named views/index.html on different packages might cause confusing inconsistencies)

With Spring if you configure the classpath scanning properly it should take into account jar packages on the classpath.

With Thymeleaf, try setup a TemplateResolver with prefix such as `classpath:/templates/`, then on different modules setup a folder structure such as `src/main/resources/templates/package-a/foo.html`, `src/main/resources/templates/package-b/foo.html`. I haven't yet tried this, and not 100% sure the class loader can merge these alright.

Comment: Yeah, qualified names in this case are obligatory and it actually works, but I stuck with related problem. It is resources loading like images, css and stuff like that.
Now i am not sure that I want to achieve a good thing. It starts to be a little messy.

Comment: You might consider using multiple wars, one for each context root. However you might not have session data sharing between wars

Comment: Actually, putting resources in /META-INF/resources allows them to be treates as if they were put in web-app structure in target web-app project.